# What does "no more Dutch" mean? "No more words"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, register

"Red Dead: Redemption"

> No more Dutch, and no more you.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zvPMrrps6o

12:15 / 11:40:13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not played this game, nor am I familiar with the story line. But I did a little basic digging and I found out that '***[Dutch](http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/Dutch_van_der_Linde)***' refers to one of the primary antagonists, in the whole RDR series.

From the video you have shared, the speaker is saying that he is in control, and insists that neither the listener, nor Dutch van der Linde is calling the shots.

Comment: When "Dutch" is a nickname, as it is here, "Mr Dutch" is not idiomatic. It would be like saying "Mr Bugsy" when referring to the criminal Bugsy Mallone.

Answer (score 3):

**no more + someone |  something** is a curt, colloquial way of saying that the thing or the person has been eliminated, "taken out of the picture"; often it is a way of saying that a problem has been solved by eliminating the person. In gangster movies, for example, when mobsters are planning to "bump someone off" (have them killed), the dialog might run something like this:

> We'll have Mikey, here, meet Johnny at the Go-Go Club. They'll go into the back room to discuss business, and then, no more Johnny.

Johnny will exist no more. He will be gone.

P.S. The phrase is often used in TV commercials for products that eliminate something.

> With Blammo laundry detergent, no more ring-around-the-collar.
>
> Spray on some Zippity, and no more rust!